# Is there a better or more efficient way to filter with linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections, filtering

I have a collection that contains a collection of attributes.  Each attribute has a type and an Id.  I need to filter the collection where the attribute ids are or'd within a group of attribute types but the attribute types are and'd.  I came up with the following and wonder if there is a better way.

```
foreach (var ag in andAttrGrpIds)
{
  filteredModels = filteredModels.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.Any(pa => pa.AttributeType==ag && orAttributes.Contains(pa.AttributeId))).ToList();            
}
```

In the above snippet, andAttrGrpIds and orAttributes are arrays of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
var filteredModels = from model in originalModels

                     let mAttribs = from pa in model.ProductAttributes
                                    where orAttributes.Contains(pa.AttributeId)
                                    select pa.AttributeType

                     where !andAttrGrpIds.Except(mAttribs).Any()

                     select model;
```

Now that's more readable and (probably)  has a better performance  profile.

The idea is to get the set of all 'qualifying' product attribute-types from each model and then test if *all* the `andAttrGrpIds` are present in this set.

By the way, your naming conventions seem quite strange: The `andAttrGrpIds` collection appears to actually represent a collection of attribute-*types*.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have take this and merged it with the other part of the equation where one of the attribute types child values are and values.  reducing what used to be a 2 step process to a single statement which is what I was looking to do.

Comment: It is located here

filteredModels = from model in allModels
      let mAttribs = from pa in model.ProductAttributes
         where orAttributes.Contains(pa.AttributeId)
         select pa.AttributeType
     let objAttribIds = model.ProductAttributes.Select(pa => pa.AttributeId)
     where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(andAttributes[0]) && andAttributes.Count ()==1) || !andAttributes.Except(objAttribIds).Any()
     where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(andAttrGrpIds[0]) && andAttrGrpIds.Count ()==1) || !andAttrGrpIds.Except(mAttribs).Any()
      select model;